# PCB LED BIN/Group select?

Tags: led

Beginner in electronics, I'm trying to make a PCB LED under KiCad.

Everything is fine, but I can not understand the BIN (Group) forward voltage of the led ...

For example with OSRAM OSLON Square LEDs :

https://www.osram.com/ecat/OSLON%C2%AE%20Square%20GH%20CSSRM4.24/com/en/class_pim_web_catalog_103489/prd_pim_device_10285510/

In general characteristics, we have :

```
- Forward Current : 100 mA - 1400 mA
- Forward Voltage : 1.80 V - 2.20 V
```

We need to select a BIN/Group :

[image]

It means that if I choose the BIN corresponding to E2, with a forward voltage of 2.0V maximum, the current would be about 700mA maximum (and not 1400mA) ?

If I select the bin F2, with a forward voltage of 2.20V maximum, the current would be ~1400 mA ?

This means that by choosing the BIN F2, I could not have a current of 700 mA ?

[image]

Sorry for the incomprehension, my project would be to use a 700mA driver, but I do not know which BIN choose ...

Thanks.

Best Regards.

Comment: Unless you know which bin you are getting, you need to design your driver/system to account for the full range from minimum to maximum Vf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The If for the bins are the test current, which means the led will have 1.8V at 700mA for bin E1.

This is not the maximum rated current, which is also stated on the datasheet at 1'400mA.

If you drive the LEDs in current (LED Driver), it does not matter as long as you have enough overhead voltage.

If you limit the current with a resistor, you will have some slight intensity differences between the bins.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Yes, my LED PCB will be powered with a constant current LED driver (700mA).

I understand better now, I will still have a question :

For example for the BIN E1, what is the min 1.80V range at 1.90V max with a current of 700mA ? This is a tolerance ? They are both indicating with If = 700mA (What I did not understand) ?

This means that with the BIN F2, I will have a tension between 2.10V and 2.20V at 700 mA ?

did I understand well ?

Comment: Just means it's the bin tolerance, higher or lower it will go to another bin.

Comment: @DLNGF FYI: when Osram sorts those Leds into bins, they drive them with regulated 700mA. They then measure the voltage drop and put it into the corresponding bin.